# Flutter video player doesn't work in release (web)

Tags: flutter, dart, video-streaming, release

The video player is working perfectly fine when I use it on Localhost but when I publish it, it doesn't work. What should I do? What can be the problem? (It also works on Android and iOS) The widget url is a download url from firebase storage.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';


class Video_player_Widget extends StatefulWidget {
  const Video_player_Widget({Key? key, required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  final String url;

  @override
  State<Video_player_Widget> createState() => _video_playerWidget();
}

@override
class _video_playerWidget extends State<Video_player_Widget> {

  late VideoPlayerController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller =
    VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          controller.setVolume(0);
          controller.play();
          controller.setLooping(false);
        });
      });

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      extendBody: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        title: Text(""),
        shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                      child: Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          VideoPlayer(controller),
                          _ControlsOverlay(controller: controller),
                          VideoProgressIndicator(controller, allowScrubbing: true, colors: VideoProgressColors(playedColor: Colors.lightBlue[900]!),),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ])
          ]
      ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to set the volume to 0 but that didn't worked for me.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web ?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that.

Comment: if you dont see the video on deployed version, did you try different brwosers, is there a single browser working as expected?

Comment: I have tried google chrome and safari but it didn't work on any of them

Comment: I have also tried bing and opera but it also didn't work on any of them

Comment: Uncaught UnimplementedError: init() has not been implemented.
    at Object.e (main.dart.js:3919:3)
    at axa.A8 (main.dart.js:94788:14)
    at Object.q1 (main.dart.js:26019:16)
    at main.dart.js:94608:14
    at aCw.a (main.dart.js:5190:62)
    at aCw.$2 (main.dart.js:37810:14)
    at Object.H (main.dart.js:5176:10)
    at Gm.qo (main.dart.js:94615:10)
    at a1g.aE (main.dart.js:93493:3)
    at iO.DV (main.dart.js:73697:14)

This is the error that it gives me

Comment: I have solved this. Repleaced late VideoPlayerController controller; with VideoPlayerController? controller

Answer (score 0):

**This code works me! In release mode.**

**you should fetch the url inside the onTap.**

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
   var url ='https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4';

    showDialog(
     context: context,
     builder: (BuildContext 
                 context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Video_player_Widget(videoUrl: url),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          child: const Text('Back'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the dialog
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
   },
  );
 },
),
```

Note: it works when I set it inside the onTap.